# How to turn QLineEdit background into a Progress Bar

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qlineedit, qprogressbar

The code creates a single dialog with `QLineEdit` and a `QPushButton`.
When the button is clicked I would like the `QLineEdit` to turn into a progress bar that would show a progress of the process triggered with the push of the button. When the process is completed the `QLineEdit` should get back to its normal "LineEdit" look. How to achieve this?

[image]

Here is the Photoshop-ed idea:

[image]

A progress bar could be a thin line at the bottom of QLineEdit:
[image]

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import time

class Dialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QDialog .__init__(self, parent)
        mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit('ITEM 001')
        mainLayout.addWidget(lineEdit)
        button = QtGui.QPushButton('Push Button')
        button.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)
        mainLayout.addWidget(button)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

    def buttonClicked(self):
        print 'button clicked'
        for i in range(3):
            time.sleep(1)
            print '...processing %s'%i

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    window = Dialog()
    window.resize(300, 50)
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: I think that I would use the setPalette method of QLineEdit. Similarly to how you set the background of a QLineEdit. Try look for how to set backgrounds using e.g. an image.

Comment: Sure, it is a good idea! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PyQt4 the `QLinearGradient` gets a horizontal orientation.
While PySide it seems handles it like it is a vertical gradient. 
The code creates a `QLineEdit` with its background color set via `palette.setBrush(QPalette.Base, QBrush(QLinearGradient))`. Button push raises the progress bar value by 10%.

[image]

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import time


class Dialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    value = 0.001
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QDialog .__init__(self, parent)
        mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()

        self.lineedit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.setValues()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.lineedit)
        button = QtGui.QPushButton('Calculate')
        button.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)
        mainLayout.addWidget(button)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

    def setValues(self):
        self.lineedit.setText('progress %s'%self.value)
        palette = self.lineedit.palette()
        QRectF = QtCore.QRectF(self.lineedit.rect())
        gradient = QtGui.QLinearGradient(QRectF.topLeft(), QRectF.topRight())
        gradient.setColorAt(self.value-0.001, QtGui.QColor('#f99e41'))
        gradient.setColorAt(self.value, QtGui.QColor('#ffffff'))
        gradient.setColorAt(self.value+0.001, QtGui.QColor('#ffffff'))
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Base, QtGui.QBrush(gradient))
        self.lineedit.setPalette(palette)

    def buttonClicked(self):
        if self.value >0.9:
            self.value = 0.001
        else:
            self.value=self.value+0.1

        self.setValues()
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    window = Dialog()
    window.resize(300, 50)
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

For PySide where the gradient might be horizontal:

```
import PySide.QtCore as QtCore
import PySide.QtGui as QtGui

class Dialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    value = 1.00
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QDialog .__init__(self, parent)
        mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()

        self.lineedit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.setValues()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.lineedit)
        button = QtGui.QPushButton('Calculate')
        button.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)
        mainLayout.addWidget(button)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

    def setValues(self):
        self.lineedit.setText('progress %s'%self.value)
        palette = self.lineedit.palette()
        QRectF = QtCore.QRectF(self.lineedit.rect())
        gradient = QtGui.QLinearGradient(QRectF.topLeft(), QRectF.topRight())
        gradient.setColorAt(self.value-0.001, QtGui.QColor('#ffffff'))
        gradient.setColorAt(self.value, QtGui.QColor('#f99e41'))
        gradient.setColorAt(self.value+0.001, QtGui.QColor('#f99e41'))
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Base, QtGui.QBrush(gradient))
        self.lineedit.setPalette(palette)

    def buttonClicked(self):
        if self.value <0.1:
            self.value = 1.00
        else:
            self.value=self.value-0.1

        self.setValues()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    window = Dialog()
    window.resize(300, 50)
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if progress < 99:
    percent = progress / 100
    self.lineedit.setStyleSheet('background: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop: 0 #1bb77b, stop: ' + str(percent) + ' #1bb77b, stop: ' + str(percent+ 0.001) + ' rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), stop: 1 white)')

else:
    self.lineedit.setStyleSheet('background-color: white')
```

Comment: Found it easiest with a few lines of code.