# Make QPushButton as Progress Bar in PyQt or PySide

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

My question is similar to what is mentioned in this thread for QPushButtion instead of QLineEdit
[How to turn QLineEdit background into a Progress Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36972132/how-to-turn-qlineedit-background-into-a-progress-bar).

Here is what I tried to implement which works but looks ugly. Content of **main.py**:

```
#!/bin/env python
import sys
from PySide6 import QtWidgets
from main_ui import Ui_Dialog


class Progress(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.value = 0

        self.ui.btn.clicked.connect(self.updateProgress)

    def updateProgress(self):
        if self.value > 1:
            self.value = 0
            self.ui.btn_progress.setStyleSheet('background-color: white')
        else:
            self.value = self.value + 0.1
        self.ui.label.setText(str(self.value))
        self.ui.btn_progress.setStyleSheet(('background: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop: 0 #1bb77b, stop: ' +
                                            (str(self.value)) + ' #1bb77b, stop: ' + str(self.value + 0.001) + ' rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), stop: 1 white)'))


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Progress()
window.show()
app.exec()
```

Here is the content of main_ui.py file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

################################################################################
## Form generated from reading UI file 'test_dialog.ui'
##
## Created by: Qt User Interface Compiler version 6.5.1
##
## WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost when recompiling UI file!
################################################################################

from PySide6.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QDate, QDateTime, QLocale,
    QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint, QRect,
    QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide6.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor,
    QFont, QFontDatabase, QGradient, QIcon,
    QImage, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPainter,
    QPalette, QPixmap, QRadialGradient, QTransform)
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QDialog, QLabel, QPushButton,
    QSizePolicy, QVBoxLayout, QWidget)

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        if not Dialog.objectName():
            Dialog.setObjectName(u"Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(680, 97)
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(Dialog)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout")
        self.btn_progress = QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.btn_progress.setObjectName(u"btn_progress")

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.btn_progress)

        self.label = QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setObjectName(u"label")

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)

        self.btn = QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.btn.setObjectName(u"btn")

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.btn)


        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("Dialog", u"Dialog", None))
        self.btn_progress.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Dialog", u"Progress Button", None))
        self.label.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Dialog", u"<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">Progress Value : </span></p></body></html>", None))
        self.btn.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Dialog", u"PushButton", None))
    # retranslateUi
```

Is it possible to implement the above code without gradient color so that to make it beautiful?

Comment: "make it beautiful" is a completely subjective concept. Please clarify exactly what you want.

Comment: I do not want a gradient color scheme as progress. How do I make it a solid color?

Comment: Just use the proper colors. Replace `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)` with `white`.